# Mongodb aggregation: restore structure after unwinding nested arrays

Tags: mongodb

Say I have the following aggregation:

```
db.foo.aggregation([
  { $unwind: '$bar' },
  // match something on bar
  { $unwind: '$bar.baz' },
  // match something on bar.baz
])
```

What is the procedure to regroup the unwound arrays back to the same structure they were originally in?

(Note - we are using mongodb 3.0)

For clarity, the main purpose of this is to pre-filter the data before the server receives it, so that only certain bar's and baz's are returned.

Comment: `$group` but you can match subdocuments without `$unwind`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Comment: $replaceRoot seems to be in 3.4, alas -- I've amended the question to say we're on 3.0.

I've tried matching, but I find this returns the whole array if any documents in it match, not just the matching documents

Comment: `$replaceRoot` does something completely different to what you apparently think it does. People had the same confusion with `$$ROOT` that it was some kind of "magical restore". **It is not**. As noted earlier, you use `$group` and `$push` to reconstruct an "unwound" array. But there is no detail in your question to explain why you are doing this, or even the `$unwind`. Using MongoDB 3.0 even, it "may" not be necessary to `$unwind` at all. Depends on what you actually do. Edit your question to make that clearer.

Comment: `$replaceRoot` is just a convenient method to return the original document, but apparently it is not what you are after. Please update the question with example document and expected output. `$group` should work to combine arrays back.